# Ruby - Find REGEX match position and w the losest match apply the regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of several REGEX expressions

```
sample_text = 'lots of text'

regex_1 = / stuff 1 /
regex_2 = / different stuff 2 /
regex_3 = / different stuff 3 /
regex_4 = / different stuff 4 /
regex_5 = / different stuff 5 /
```

What I would like to know how to elegantly do is for each regex, search in the sample_text and return the match position.

I then want to use the regex that has the lowest/closest match position from the start of the sample_text

Thoughts? Suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample_text = 'lots of text'

regexes = [
  / stuff 1 /,
  / different stuff 2 /,
  / different stuff 3 /,
  / different stuff 4 /,
  / different stuff 5 /
]

infinity = 1.0/0
regex_to_use = regexes.min_by{ |re| sample_text.index(re) || infinity }
```

You just put the regexes into an array and try them one after another. The one with the lowest match index wins. In the above code, we classify regexes that don't match at all as infinitely away from the start of the string. If more than one regex with the same proximity is found, the first is returned.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. What happens is no matches are found?

Comment: first regexp will be returned. In case if you'll preselect regexpes which will match your sample, then if no matches are found `nil` will be returned

Answer (score 2):

```
regexes = [ regex_1, regex_2, regex_3, regex_4, regex_5 ].
  select{|r| sample_text =~ r }.
  sort_by{|r| sample_text =~ r}
regexes.first
#=> /some regex here/
```

It will sort regexps by their match positions.

1. `sample_text =~ r` returns match position
2. `sort_by` will sort our array by match positions

**UPD**

As @Holger Just mentioned `match` can return `nil` which will breaks our `sort_by`, so we should `select` only those regexes which will `match` our `smaple_text`

and short little hacky way:

```
[ regex_1, regex_2, regex_3, regex_4, regex_5 ].sort_by{|r| 1.0/(sample_text=~r).to_i}
```

Comment: fl00r can you give a little desc of what this does?

Comment: Thanks, I gave it an up vote but am leaning towards accepting Holger's answer as it seems cleaner and easier to read. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: Since the purpose is to just extract the best match, sorting the whole array seems to be doing extra computation, which is not preferable from the point of view of efficiency.

Comment: as I understand `min_by` will sort and return first element as well

Comment: As you sure? Sort will end up giving you more information than picking up the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_text = 'lots of text'

regexes = [
    / stuff 1 /,
    / different stuff 2 /,
    / different stuff 3 /,
    / different stuff 4 /,
    / different stuff 5 /
]

positions = regexes.map{|re| sample_text.index(re)}
regex_to_use = regexes[positions.index(positions.compact.min)]
```

Comment: I have made a huge mistake. I fixed it.